# How To Copy .NET User Settings During EXE Upgrade

Tags: c#, winforms, settings

I am working on an application that uses .NET User settings to manage application preferences.  I have noticed that if I add a new user setting and then update the customer's executable, their preferences (i.e. user settings) are lost.  Is there a way to ensure that these settings are copied without actually running an upgrade or conversion program to perform the update?  Right now, our code base is very volatile and we are frequently just updating executables and DLL files.

Comment: Are you installing/upgrading using ClickOnce?

Comment: Currently, we are not using ClickOnce.  The developers have just been building a release and more or less updating the executable and dependent DLL files.